# Unable to install a custom Python package for Python 2.7 using pip and private artifact repository

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I have created a custom Python package for Python 2.7. I uploaded it to a private Artifactory repository using the following commands. Note these commands were run in Python 3 container:

```
pip install -U pip wheel setuptools
pip install -U twine
pip install -U python-dotenv
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
twine upload --repository-url https://artifactory.xxx.org/api/pypi/pypi -u <myUser> -p <myPassword> dist/*
```

The upload works well and uploads two artifacts

- `my_package-0.4.2_py2-py3-none-any.whl`
- `my_package-0.4.2-py2.tar.gz`

Note that in `setup.py` I have tried different flavors of `python_requires`. Such as:

- `python_requires='<=2.7',`
- `python_requires='<3.6',`
- `python_requires='>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*, !=3.5.*, !=3.6.*, !=3.7.*, !=3.8.*, !=3.9.*, !=3.10.*',`
- No `python_requires` at all

Then I run a Docker container `python:2.7-slim-buster` and every time I try to pip install my package, I get an error saying the Python version does not match:

```
pip install --index-url https://artifactory.xxx.org/api/pypi/pypi/simple my_package
[...]
Looking in indexes: https://artifactory.xxx.org/api/pypi/pypi/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement my_package (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for my_package
```

When I look into pip install in verbose mode, I also get more details that my Python version does not match (which is not true since this is running in Py2.7)

```
pip install -v --index-url https://artifactory.xxx.org/api/pypi/pypi/simple my_package
[…]
Skipping link: Python version is incorrect: https://artifactory.xxx.org/api/pypi/pypi/my-package/0.4.2-py2/my_package-0.4.2-py2.tar.gz#md5=1f74fb81ad9a5225df00c787d26df015 (from https://artifactory.xxx.org/api/pypi/pypi/simple/my-package)
Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: py3-none-any: https://artifactory.xxx.org/api/pypi/pypi/my-package/0.4.2-py2/my_package-0.4.2_py2-py3-none-any.whl#md5=5f9bd6d61c49180826b7885f623f1030 (from https://artifactory.xxx.org/api/pypi/pypi/simple/my-package/)
[…]
Skipping link: Python version is incorrect: https://artifactory.xxx.org/api/pypi/pypi/my-package/0.4.3-py2/my_package-0.4.3-py2.tar.gz#md5=84b2ca0ab20d05756d687f1bc86992f0 (from https://artifactory.xxx.org/api/pypi/pypi/simple/my-package/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*, !=3.5.*, !=3.6.*, !=3.7.*, !=3.8.*, !=3.9.*, !=3.10.*)
Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: py3-none-any: https://artifactory.xxx.org/api/pypi/pypi/my-package/0.4.3-py2/my_package-0.4.3_py2-py3-none-any.whl#md5=d38c9263fbf485dd4cbabbdf24072e11 (from https://artifactory.xxx.org/api/pypi/pypi/simple/my-package/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*, !=3.5.*, !=3.6.*, !=3.7.*, !=3.8.*, !=3.9.*, !=3.10.*)
[…]
Etc…
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Is it reasonable to create a py2.7 package using py3?

**UPDATE**

I was able to package my custom Python package for Python 2.7 by running the following commands in a Python 2.7 Docker container. I got the same error as above.

```
pip install -U pip wheel setuptools
pip install -U twine
pip install -U python-dotenv
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
twine upload --repository-url https://artifactory.xxx.org/api/pypi/pypi -u <myUser> -p <myPassword> dist/*
```

Comment: From what I can see it seems that you artifacts have been uploaded with the name `craft_sdk` and you are trying to install `my_package`. Maybe you are installing the wrong package?

Comment: Actually this was just a typo in my question, I was trying to obfuscate the name of the package by replacing it by my_package here ;-) I confirm you the name was consistent in my tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. I was packaging my custom Py2.7 package in a Py3 environment. It seems Python will by default assume this package requires Py3. **The packaging should be done with Python 2.7.**
2. The version name of my package was `0.4.2-py2`, the suffix `-py2` is converted to `_py2` by `bdist_wheel` and was conflicting with `bdist_wheel` in some ways because the package it creates also contains `py2` keyword. Example: `my_package-0.4.2_py2-py2-none-any.whl`. So I renamed my version name to `0.4.2.py2` and it worked.